# gojs dinamical dropdown choices for node and link text

Tags: javascript, python, gojs

I want to make custom choices dropdown for users to edit node and link text.

[image]

So far, I used this code to make user select nodes and links text selectable in dropdown list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>State Chart</title>
<meta name="description" content="A finite state machine chart with editable and interactive features." />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='go.js')}}"></script>

<!-- custom text editors -->
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorSelectBox.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorRadioButtons.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorSelectBox.js')}}"></script>


<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='DataInspector.js')}}"></script>

<link href="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='DataInspector.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<style>

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

</style>
<script id="code">

    var nodeChoices = ['choice 1', 'choice 2', 'choice 3', 'choice 4', 'choice 5'];
    const originalNodeChoices = ['choice 1', 'choice 2', 'choice 3', 'choice 4', 'choice 5'];
    var linkChoices = ['link choice 1', 'link choice 2', 'link choice 3', 'link choice 4', 'link choice 5'];
    const originalLinkChoices = ['link choice 1', 'link choice 2', 'link choice 3', 'link choice 4', 'link choice 5'];

    function init() {

        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
            // start everything in the middle of the viewport
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            // have mouse wheel events zoom in and out instead of scroll up and down
            "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,
            // support double-click in background creating a new node
            "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { text: "new node" },
            // enable undo & redo
            "textEditingTool.defaultTextEditor": window.TextEditorSelectBox,
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
            "layout": new go.ForceDirectedLayout(),
            "ModelChanged": function(e) {
                //console.log("Diagram model changed!");

              if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove && e.modelChange === "linkDataArray") {
                console.log("eee its linkDataArray");
                console.log(e);
                var linkdata = e.oldValue;
                console.log("linkdata");
                console.log(linkdata);
                var oldstr = linkdata.text;
                console.log("oldstr");
                console.log(oldstr);

                if (!oldstr) return;
                var customModelData = e.model.modelData.choices;
                var choices = e.model.modelData.choices.linkChoices;
                console.log("choices");
                console.log(choices);
                var idx = choices.indexOf(oldstr);
                if (idx < 0) {
                  console.log("adding choice: " + oldstr);
                  var newchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(choices);
                  newchoices.push(oldstr);
                  e.model.set(e.model.modelData, "choices", newchoices);
                }
              }else if(e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove && e.modelChange === "nodeDataArray"){
                    console.log("eee its nodeDataArray");
              }
              /*
              else{
                console.log("elseeeeeee111!");
                console.log("e.change");
                console.log(e.change);
                console.log("e.modelChange");
                console.log(e.modelChange);
              }*/
            }
        });

        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", JSON.parse('{{ link_choices | tojson | safe}}'));
        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", ["one", "two", "three"]);
        console.log("myDiagram.model.modelData");
        console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData);
        console.log("myDiagram.model.modelData.choices");
        console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData.choices);


        // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
            var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
            if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
            var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
            if (myDiagram.isModified) {
                if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
            } 
            else {
                if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
            }
        });

        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("textEdited", function(e) {
            console.log("Text is edited");
            console.log(e);

            //CHECK IF LINK,
            //IF YES REMOVE THAT OPTION FROM LIST

        });

        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionDeleting", function(e) {
            console.log("inside SelectionDeleting");
            console.log(e);

            //CHECK IF LINK,
            //IF YES PUT THAT OPTION BACK IN OPTION LIST

        });

            // define the Node template
        myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
          $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
              {
                parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                stroke: null,
                portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                toLinkable: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                cursor: "pointer"
              }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                editable: true,  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                //textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons, // defined in textEditorRadioButtons.js
                // this specific TextBlock has its own choices:

                textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons,
                textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
                    console.log("textEdited nodeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!!!");
                  var choices = tb.diagram.model.modelData.choices.nodeChoices;
                  console.log("choices");
                  console.log(choices);
                  console.log("newstr");
                  console.log(newstr);
                  console.log("oldstr");
                  console.log(oldstr);
                  var idx = choices.indexOf(newstr);
                  if (idx >= 0 && oldstr !== newstr ) {
                    console.log(choices);
                    console.log("choices");
                    console.log(choices);
                    console.log("removing choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                    var newchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(choices);

                    newchoices.splice(idx, 1);
                    console.log("after remove");
                    console.log(newchoices);
                    var currentChoicesFromModel = tb.diagram.model.modelData.choices;
                    console.log("currentChoicesFromModel");
                    console.log(currentChoicesFromModel);
                    currentChoicesFromModel.nodeChoices = newchoices;
                    console.log("currentChoicesFromModel after update: ");
                    console.log(currentChoicesFromModel);
                    tb.diagram.model.set(tb.diagram.model.modelData, "choices", currentChoicesFromModel);
                    //tb.editable = false;  // don't allow choice again
                  }else{
                        console.log("elseeeeee");
                  }
                },
                //choices: JSON.parse('{{ choices | tojson | safe}}')
                choices: nodeChoices
              },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );

        myDiagram.nodeTemplate.selectionAdornmentTemplate =
        $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
            $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, { stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2, fill: null }),
            $(go.Placeholder)
        ),
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
            { alignment: go.Spot.Top, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom },
            $("Button",
                { click: editText },  // defined below, to support editing the text of the node
                $(go.TextBlock, "t",
                { font: "bold 10pt sans-serif", desiredSize: new go.Size(15, 15), textAlign: "center" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            { // drawLink is defined below, to support interactively drawing new links
                click: drawLink,  // click on Button and then click on target node
                actionMove: drawLink  // drag from Button to the target node
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L8 0 8 12 14 12 M12 10 L14 12 12 14" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            {
                actionMove: dragNewNode,  // defined below, to support dragging from the button
                _dragData: { text: "?????", color: "lightgray" },  // node data to copy
                click: clickNewNode  // defined below, to support a click on the button
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L3 0 3 10 6 10 x F1 M6 6 L14 6 14 14 6 14z", fill: "gray" })
          )
        )
      );

    //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", JSON.parse('{{ link_choices | tojson | safe}}'));
    //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", ["one", "two", "three"]);
    console.log("myDiagram.model.modelData");
    console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData);
    console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData.choices);

    function editText(e, button) {
        //console.log(e);

      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      console.log("node");
      //console.log(node);
      e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
      //$("#nodeText").val(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
    }

    function drawLink(e, button) {
      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.linkingTool;
      tool.startObject = node.port;
      e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
      tool.doActivate();
    }

   // used by both clickNewNode and dragNewNode to create a node and a link
    // from a given node to the new node
    function createNodeAndLink(data, fromnode) {
        var diagram = fromnode.diagram;
        var model = diagram.model;
        var nodedata = model.copyNodeData(data);
        model.addNodeData(nodedata);
        var newnode = diagram.findNodeForData(nodedata);
        var linkdata = model.copyLinkData({});
        model.setFromKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(fromnode.data));
        model.setToKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(newnode.data));
        model.addLinkData(linkdata);
        diagram.select(newnode);
        return newnode;
    }

    // the Button.click event handler, called when the user clicks the "N" button
    function clickNewNode(e, button) {
        var data = button._dragData;
        if (!data) return;
        e.diagram.startTransaction("Create Node and Link");
        var fromnode = button.part.adornedPart;
        var newnode = createNodeAndLink(button._dragData, fromnode);
        newnode.location = new go.Point(fromnode.location.x + 200, fromnode.location.y);
        e.diagram.commitTransaction("Create Node and Link");
    }

    // the Button.actionMove event handler, called when the user drags within the "N" button
    function dragNewNode(e, button) {
        var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
        if (tool.isBeyondDragSize()) {
            var data = button._dragData;
            if (!data) return;
            e.diagram.startTransaction("button drag");  // see doDeactivate, below
            var newnode = createNodeAndLink(data, button.part.adornedPart);
            newnode.location = e.diagram.lastInput.documentPoint;
            // don't commitTransaction here, but in tool.doDeactivate, after drag operation finished
            // set tool.currentPart to a selected movable Part and then activate the DraggingTool
            tool.currentPart = newnode;
            e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
            tool.doActivate();
        }
    }

    // using dragNewNode also requires modifying the standard DraggingTool so that it
    // only calls commitTransaction when dragNewNode started a "button drag" transaction;
    // do this by overriding DraggingTool.doDeactivate:
    var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
    tool.doDeactivate = function() {
        // commit "button drag" transaction, if it is ongoing; see dragNewNode, above
        if (tool.diagram.undoManager.nestedTransactionNames.elt(0) === "button drag") {
            tool.diagram.commitTransaction();
        }
        go.DraggingTool.prototype.doDeactivate.call(tool);  // call the base method
    };

    // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
            curve: go.Link.Bezier, 
            adjusting: go.Link.Stretch,
            reshapable: true, 
            relinkableFrom: true, 
            relinkableTo: true,
            toShortLength: 3
        },
        new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("curviness"),
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
            { strokeWidth: 1.5 }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
            { toArrow: "standard", stroke: null }),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape,  // the label background, which becomes transparent around the edges
            {
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Radial", { 0: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 0.3: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 1: "rgba(240, 240, 240, 0)" }),
                stroke: null
            }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                background: "white",
                editable: true,
                textEditor: window.TextEditorSelectBox, // defined in extensions/textEditorSelectBox.js
                textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
                  var choices = tb.diagram.model.modelData.choices.linkChoices;
                  console.log("choices");
                  console.log(choices);
                  console.log("newstr");
                  console.log(newstr);
                  console.log("oldstr");
                  console.log(oldstr);
                  var idx = choices.indexOf(newstr);
                  if (idx >= 0 && oldstr !== newstr ) {
                    console.log(choices);
                    console.log("choices");
                    console.log(choices);
                    console.log("removing choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                    var newchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(choices);
                    newchoices.splice(idx, 1);
                    tb.diagram.model.set(tb.diagram.model.modelData.choices.linkChoices, "choices", newchoices);
                    //tb.editable = false;  // don't allow choice again
                  }else{
                        console.log("elseeeeee");
                  }
                }
              },
            // editing the text automatically updates the model data
            //new go.Binding("text"),
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay(),
            new go.Binding("choices").ofModel())
        )
    );


    var inspector = new Inspector('myInspectorDiv', myDiagram,
    {
        // uncomment this line to only inspect the named properties below instead of all properties on each object:
        // includesOwnProperties: false,
        properties: {
            "text": { },
            // an example of specifying the type
            "password": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'password' },
            // key would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it read-only also:
            "key": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent },
            // color would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it a color also:
            "color": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'color' },
            // Comments and LinkComments are not in any node or link data (yet), so we add them here:
            "Comments": { show: Inspector.showIfNode  },
            "flag": { show: Inspector.showIfNode, type: 'checkbox' },
            "LinkComments": { show: Inspector.showIfLink },
            "isGroup": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent }
        }
    });

    // read in the JSON data from flask
    loadGraphData();

    }

    function loadGraphData() {
        var graphDataString = JSON.parse('{{ diagramData | tojson | safe}}');
        //console.log("graphDataString");
        //console.log(graphDataString);

        var allChoices = JSON.parse('{{ allChoices | tojson | safe}}');
        console.log("allChoices");
        console.log(allChoices);

        myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(graphDataString);
        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", ["one", "two", "three"]);

        var customModelData = {
            "linkChoices": linkChoices, "nodeChoices": nodeChoices
        };

        myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", allChoices);
        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", JSON.parse('{{ link_choices | tojson | safe}}'));
        //myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", customModelData);
        console.log("whole model modelData");
        console.log(myDiagram.model.modelData);
    }

    function saveGraphData(form, event) {
        console.log("inside saveGraphData");
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
        form.submit();
    }

    function zoomToFit(){
        console.log("inside zoomToFit");
        myDiagram.zoomToRect(myDiagram.documentBounds);
    }

    function zoomIn(){
        console.log("inside zoomIn");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.increaseZoom();
    }
    function zoomOut(){
        console.log("inside zoomOut");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.decreaseZoom();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">



    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"> <a href="#"> CUSTOM CHOICES MODE </a>  </li>


                <li> <a href="{{ url_for('main') }}">Free editing mode</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="{{ url_for('graphMode1') }}">Fill mode</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="{{ url_for('graphMode2') }}">Custom choices mode</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="{{ url_for('graphMode3') }}">Locked choices mode</a> </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">


                <div id=formWrapper style="padding: 30px;">

                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-secondary" id="menu-toggle" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Toggle Menu</a>

                    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/updateResultFile" name="updateResultFileForm" 
                    id="updateResultFileForm" 
                    onsubmit="saveGraphData(this, event);">

                        <div id="graphWrapper" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                            <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100%; height: 800px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
                            <div style="display: none;"><input id="mySavedModel" name="mySavedModel"></div>

                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> Save <i class="fa fa-save"> </i> </button>

                        </div>

                    </form>

                    <div id="myInspectorDiv">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomToFit()"> Zoom to fit  <i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomIn()"> Zoom in  <i class="fa fa-search-plus"> </i> </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomOut()"> Zoom out  <i class="fa fa-search-minus"> </i> </button>
                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        var menuOpen = false;
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

            if(menuOpen){
                menuOpen = false;
                $("#myDiagramDiv").css({border: "solid 1px black"});
            }else{
                menuOpen = true;
                $("#myDiagramDiv").css({border: ""});
            }
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So basicly I have made custom choices for nodes and links. For example, for node I have these choices:

- node choice 1
- node choice 2
- node choice 3

and for links I have these choices:

- link choice 1
- link choice 2
- link choice 3

What I want to accomplish is that when I select "node choice 1" from dropdown list on one node, that that option "node choice 1" can not be selected again for another node. But if user deletes node, or sets empty selection on node text, "node choice 1" must be available again.

Same thing goes for links.

I think my code works fine for links, but I have problems with detecting node text changes and updating dataModel content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have missed this before.  Here's some code that answers your question by implementing it:

```
function init() {
  var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

  myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
      {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
        "ModelChanged": function(e) {     // just for demonstration purposes,
          if (e.isTransactionFinished) {  // show the model data in the page's TextArea
            document.getElementById("mySavedModel").textContent = e.model.toJson();
          }
          if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove) {
            if (e.modelChange === "linkDataArray") {
              var linkdata = e.oldValue;
              var oldstr = linkdata.text;
              if (!oldstr) return;
              var linkchoices = e.model.modelData.linkchoices;
              var idx = linkchoices.indexOf(oldstr);
              if (idx < 0) {
                console.log("deletion adding link choice: " + oldstr);
                var newlinkchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(linkchoices);
                newlinkchoices.push(oldstr);
                e.model.set(e.model.modelData, "linkchoices", newlinkchoices);
              }
            } else if (e.modelChange === "nodeDataArray") {
              var nodedata = e.oldValue;
              var oldstr = nodedata.text;
              if (!oldstr) return;
              var nodechoices = e.model.modelData.nodechoices;
              var idx = nodechoices.indexOf(oldstr);
              if (idx < 0) {
                console.log("deletion adding node choice: " + oldstr);
                var newnodechoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodechoices);
                newnodechoices.push(oldstr);
                e.model.set(e.model.modelData, "nodechoices", newnodechoices);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

  myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape,
        { fill: "white", portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer" },
        new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        {
          margin: 8,
          editable: true,
          textEditor: window.TextEditorSelectBox, // defined in extensions/textEditorSelectBox.js
          textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
            if (oldstr !== newstr) {
              console.log("changing from " + oldstr + " to " + newstr);
              var model = tb.diagram.model;
              var nodechoices = model.modelData.nodechoices;
              if (!nodechoices) {
                nodechoices = [];
                model.set(model.modelData, "nodechoices", nodechoices);
              }
              var idx = nodechoices.indexOf(newstr);
              if (idx >= 0) {
                console.log("removing node choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                model.removeArrayItem(nodechoices, idx);
              }
              if (oldstr) {
                console.log("  adding node choice " + oldstr);
                model.addArrayItem(nodechoices, oldstr);
              }
            }
          }
        },
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("choices", "nodechoices").ofModel())
    );

  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(go.Link,
      $(go.Shape),
      $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "OpenTriangle" }),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        {
          background: "white",
          editable: true,
          textEditor: window.TextEditorSelectBox, // defined in extensions/textEditorSelectBox.js
          textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
            if (oldstr !== newstr) {
              console.log("changing from " + oldstr + " to " + newstr);
              var model = tb.diagram.model;
              var linkchoices = model.modelData.linkchoices;
              if (!linkchoices) {
                linkchoices = [];
                model.set(model.modelData, "linkchoices", linkchoices);
              }
              var idx = linkchoices.indexOf(newstr);
              if (idx >= 0) {
                console.log("removing link choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                model.removeArrayItem(linkchoices, idx);
              }
              if (oldstr) {
                console.log("  adding link choice " + oldstr);
                model.addArrayItem(linkchoices, oldstr);
              }
            }
          }
        },
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("choices", "linkchoices").ofModel())
    );

  myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
  [
    { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
    { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange" },
    { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
    { key: 4, text: "Delta", color: "pink" }
  ],
  [
    { from: 1, to: 2, text: "one" },
    { from: 1, to: 3, text: "two" },
    { from: 3, to: 4, text: "three" }
  ]);
  myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "nodechoices", ["Epsilon"]);
  myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "linkchoices", ["four"]);
}
```